# Submitting password by using enter key

Tags: javascript, html

this question has been asked a couple times and trust me I have read them all but none of them helped me solve my problem in particular. I am new to coding and probably need a little more help.

I want a password to be submitted when pressing enter. So far I only solved it with a mouse click:

```html
<center><body>
  <div style="font-size:12pt"/>Please enter your password:</div>
  <br>
<input id='password' type='password' style="height:30px;width:350px;font-size:14pt" />
  <br>
<a href="URL code" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">
  <br>
  <div style="font-size:13pt; color: #F99D27"/>Register now</div></a>
<script>
function validatePass(){
    if(document.getElementById('password').value == '1234'){
      return true;
    }else{
        alert('Invalid password!');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</center>
```

No where exactly do I have to enter this part for submitting the password when pressing enter?:

```js
function validateOnEnter(event) {
  var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) { // enter pressed then invoke the validation method
    validatePass();
  }
}
```

Comment: [Javascript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/).

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't standard. Please remove the deprecated and useless tags. Your code should be added to the `onkeydown` event of your `<input />` and make sure the pressed key is Enter:

```js
function validatePass() {
  var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) { // enter pressed then invoke the validation method
    if (document.getElementById('password').value == '1234') {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert('Invalid password!');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:12pt">Please enter your password:</div>
<br />
<input id='password' type='password' onkeyup="return validatePass();" />
<br />
<a href="URL code" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">
  <span style="font-size:13pt; color: #F99D27">Register now</span>
</a>
```

And you have closed all the non-closing tags while not closing the start tag closing tags. I have corrected it for you.

Also, for enter key to work, it's always better to have a `<form>` tag surrounding the inputs and giving it to the `onsubmit` event of the form. Something like this will be right:

```js
function validatePass() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value == '1234') {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Invalid password!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validatePass();">
  <div style="font-size:12pt">Please enter your password:</div>
  <br />
  <input id='password' type='password' />
  <br />
  <a href="URL code" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">
    <span style="font-size:13pt; color: #F99D27">Register now</span>
  </a>
</form>
```

---

Updated according to what OP needs. Following are the things considered:

- Using a `<form>` makes it better in terms of semantic web.
- The link should be clickable only when the password is right.

```js
function validatePass() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value == '1234') {
    document.querySelector("p a").classList.remove("disabled-link");
    document.querySelector("p a").setAttribute("href", "URLCode");
    alert("Password Accepted, click link to continue!");
  } else {
    alert('Invalid password! Try again.');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {color: #F99D27; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid; padding: 5px; line-height: 1; text-decoration: none;}
.disabled-link, .disabled-link:hover, .disabled-link:active, .disabled-link:focus {color: #ccc; text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); cursor: not-allowed;}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validatePass();">
  <p>Please enter your password and press Enter:</p>
  <input id='password' type='password' />
  <p><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="disabled-link">Register now</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Okay this works if the password is wrong, but I doesn't do anything if the password is correct. Plus, with this I can click on "Register Now" even with the password being wrong and I will still be forwarded to the page... My previous snippet didn't do that

Comment: @A.Be So what's your exact requirement? Only if the password is right, the link should be clickable?

Comment: I mean it could be a button too. THe link should be clickable regardless...but with my snippet the link was only clickable if the password was correct. I want the same with but also with using the enter button.

Comment: @A.Be I have done it. Have a look at the last snippet and tell me if it works.

Comment: I have entered it into my page. It could be that Unbounce does not support CSS (I am adding this into an HTML box there)..but it only works until the password is correct and the link is still not clickable. Is it possible to find a solution that just forwards you to the page when the password is correct (both through enter or mouse click) and shows you an error message when invalid password? (also enter and mouse click)

Comment: @A.Be You wanna say, once the password is correct, it goes to the right page?

Comment: Exactly. Once the passwort is correct I can choose whether I want to click on the "register now" or just press enter, it should both bring me to the page if the password is correct. If not, I will receive an error message if I enter or if I click on "register now"

Comment: @A.Be Yea, can do. Just add `location.href='URLToGo';` after `alert("Password Accepted, click link to continue!");`. `:D`

Comment: Now it works!!!! thanks a ton! Is there any way I can limit the CSS style rules to this part only? Currently it is changing the style for the entire page

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not *submitting* your password at all, you are checking on the client side, which is not save at all as it is openly accessible by everyone. You should do an Ajax post (and use TLS) to your server and check your password there.

Comment: TLS? You mean SSL?

Comment: @PraveenKumar SSL is the version before TSL, according to wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

By default pressing enter from a text-box which is inside a form is same as submitting the form by a button click. You need not do anything to achieve it.
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="action.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name">
        <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```